# RegisterRawInputDevices causes constant WM_INPUT messages

Tags: c++, winapi, raw-input

We have a legacy C++ application that simply needs to react to a joystick button press (it's used for footpedal control, and to react to a button press on certain cameras).  On some systems, we are having an issue where simply registering to receive input is causing a constant flood of WM_INPUT messages.  It's simply this code in the window startup:

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE rid;
memset(&rid, 0, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE));
rid.usUsagePage = 0x01;
rid.usUsage = 0x04;     // Joystick
rid.dwFlags = 0;
rid.hwndTarget = _hwnd;
if (RegisterRawInputDevices(&rid, 1, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE)) == FALSE)
    return false;
```

And WM_INPUT receives a bunch of messages with no data (bRawData is empty).  If I comment out the registration everything works as expected (but without button support, obviously).  As I said, this doesn't occur on all systems, but we have not found any common pattern among the systems it occurs on.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

Comment: Maybe the joystick is faulty?

Comment: I don't understand the issue. If you receive a `WM_INPUT` message without additional data, there's nothing to be done. Simply skip over the message. The constant stream of messages could be triggered either by malfunctioning hardware or intricacies of the driver implementation.